# Unable to open socket connection with J2ME application on HTC P3400i

Tags: java, networking, java-me

I am unable to open socket connection with J2ME application on HTC P3400i. I am able to use the same application Nokia phones. It is working good on Nokia phones. Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you using a different SIM or different access point settings? usually, socket blocks come the mobile network operator, not the handset itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are supposedly not so reliable on mobile phones.  Using HTTP, if at all possible, is a better bet.